# Inserting XML field from query error - QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON does not fix

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-insert

I need to insert a number of rows into a table using a query from another table. This issue I have is that one of the columns I am inserting is XML (in which I need to embed a value from my query) but when I try and run the insert statement in SSMS I get

Msg 1934 INSERT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'.

I have tried setting QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON but I still get the same error. I tried it within the batch and in a separate batch (the SET statement followed by GO, before the Insert statement.

I have no indexed view, filtered indexes or computed column in this table. Looking at the table properties I see Quoted Identifier is True.

Here is the essence of what I am trying to do. The columns Area, Action and EntityType are int, Data is XML and Title is nvarchar(20).

```
INSERT INTO AuditLog ( [Area], [Action], [EntityType], [Data] )
  SELECT (1,2,1,'<Name>' + [Title] + '<\Name>')
     FROM [Records] WHERE [TypeId] = 3;
```

I am able to create an XML variable and use this but I need to be able to insert multiple records and don't really want to resort to a cursor to do something that looks so simple. Even if I use simple static quoted XML or use CAST or CONVERT I have the same error.

I am running on SQL Server Standard 2016 with the latest SSMS (2019). All suggestions are gratefully received.

Comment: You've apparently ruled out a number of items that do *require* the setting to be correct but you haven't (at least in the question) ruled out things that might still have the wrong setting no matter what you're trying to set it to - so does the table have any *triggers*?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Ahha. yes I do have a trigger, so would the fix be to ensure this trigger has SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON?

Comment: Thanks Yitzhak, I did cut some corners hoping for an 'easy win' :-) I'll bear this in mind and thanks for taking the time to guide me.

Comment: In fact I do have a trigger. This has QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON but I shall explore what this does to see if this is the cause of the issue. I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON` needs to be set before you create the trigger. You cannot set it in the trigger as it will only affect procedures called by the trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue, but I was initially unsure why it worked when little had changed but eventually, I figured out that I was running the query under the context of a database that had QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF (this was where the source data was located) whereas the database where the results were being inserted had QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON, so changing the context of the execution (an Agent Job Step) fixed the issue. The source database is part of a third-party application so changing the QUOTED_IDENTIFER setting would have unknown consequences.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following conceptual example.

`XML` data type cannot be treated as `VARCHAR/NVARCHAR` data types.

The desired XML could be easily composed via `SELECT ... FOR XML ...`

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Area INT, Title XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (Area, Title) VALUES
(770, N'<root>Manager</root>');

DECLARE @target TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Area INT, [DATA] XML);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

INSERT INTO @target (Area, [DATA])
SELECT Area
    , (
    SELECT title AS [Name]
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ) AS [DATA]
FROM @tbl;

-- test
SELECT * FROM @target;
```

**Output**

```
+----+------+-----------------------------------+
| ID | Area |               DATA                |
+----+------+-----------------------------------+
|  1 |  770 | <Name><root>Manager</root></Name> |
+----+------+-----------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you. That gave me the way in I needed (using FROM XML PATH subquery). I've been able to add to that to get the exact output I wanted. I'm not able to upvote as I'm new but thank you again for your time and trouble.

Comment: Good to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. 
Please mark it as answered. You simply need to mark an answer as correct (the green check image). 
Click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. This marks the answer as "accepted"

Comment: Spoke too soon. When I tried this in my db I get the same error. Dropping the trigger made no difference, so I need to work on steps to reproduce so I can get a viable example.

Comment: I have gradually created a copy of the table and it is the XML Index that is causing the issue. I shall do some searching to see if there is a way of addressing this.

Comment: In fact, when I resolved the issue (changing the context of the database) SQL Server was quite happy with me passing a nvarchar string with XML. It's pretty relaxed about coercing data types.